# What is the Easiest way to Animate the rigid body properties of a large group of objects

Tags: animation, physics, keyframes, rigidbody

I would like to animate 500 or so shards to be "animated" rigid body at frame zero and "dynamic" at frame 550. Do I really have to set a keyframe for each individual object or is there a way to animate that rigid body property as a group?
The shards are in a group, but it appears that the rigid body for a group of objects can only be set, not animated. I've tried using an empty parent object to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Select the rigid body object and copy their properties (except for animated).]*

1. Select all rigid body object to be modified.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> click on the **Animated** property. This will change the property for *all* the selected object to the same value. Now all object have animated enabled.
3. Use this script to key the property on all of them.

```
import bpy
sel = bpy.context.selected_objects
for ob in sel:
    ob.rigid_body.keyframe_insert(data_path="enabled") 
    ob.rigid_body.keyframe_insert(data_path="kinematic")
```

Now all objects are keyed.

To remove all *Animated* keys on a frame, execute the script but replace `keyframe_insert` with `keyframe_delete`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Leander. Please add the following line to your script, and then I will mark your answer as 100% helpful by clicking the checkmark: 
ob.rigid_body.keyframe_insert(data_path="enabled")

Comment: @silvermanj7 You're welcome, I have edited the line, feel free to edit it yourself, if I misunderstood

Comment: oh i didn't realize i had the power. thanks again. :))